Error: call revert exception in Hardhat test for Lottery Contract
I'm encountering an issue while running unit tests for my Lottery smart contract using Hardhat. The error occurs during the "before each" hook, specifically when trying to call the 'getEnteranceFee' function.
Error Message:
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getEnteranceFee()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\interface.ts:427:23)
    at Contract.<anonymous> (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:400:44)
    at step (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:20:58)

Contract Code (Lottery.sol):
//SPDX-License-Modifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

// Enter the lottery (paying some amount)
// Pick a random winner (varifiably randome)
// Winner to be selected every X minutes --> completely automated

// Chainlink oracle is necessary for randomness and automated execution(Chainlink keeper)
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/automation/interfaces/AutomationCompatibleInterface.sol";

error Lottery__NotEnoughETHEntered();

error Lottery_TransferFailed();
error Lottery_NotOpen();
error Lottery_UpKeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 lotteryState);

contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBaseV2, AutomationCompatibleInterface {
    /* Type declaration*/
    enum LotteryState {
        OPEN,
        CALCULATING
    } //uint256 0=OPEN, 1=CALCULATING

    /* State Variables */
    uint256 private immutable i_enteranceFee;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;
//Lottery Variables
address private s_recentWinner;
LotteryState private s_lotteryState;
uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
uint256 private immutable i_interval;

/* Evnets*/
event LotteryEnter(address indexed player);
event RequestedLotteryWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
event WinnerPicked(address indexed winner);

/* Functions */
constructor(
    address vrfCoordinatorV2, //contract address
    uint256 enteranceFee,
    bytes32 gasLane,
    uint64 subscriptionId,
    uint32 callbackGasLimit,
    uint256 interval
) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
    i_enteranceFee = enteranceFee;
    i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
    i_gasLane = gasLane;
    i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
    i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
    s_lotteryState = LotteryState.OPEN;
    s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp; //block.timestamp is a globally known variable
    i_interval = interval;
}

function enterLottery() public payable {
    if (msg.value < i_enteranceFee) {
        revert Lottery__NotEnoughETHEntered();
    }
    if (s_lotteryState != LotteryState.OPEN) {
        revert Lottery_NotOpen();
    }
    s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));

    emit LotteryEnter(msg.sender);
}

function checkUpkeep(
    bytes memory /*checkData*/
) public override returns (bool upKeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData*/) {
    bool isOpen = (LotteryState.OPEN == s_lotteryState);
    bool timePassed = (block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval;
    bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
    bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
    upKeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance);
}

function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /*performData*/) external override {
    (bool upKeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
    if (!upKeepNeeded) {
        revert Lottery_UpKeepNotNeeded(
            address(this).balance,
            s_players.length,
            uint256(s_lotteryState)
        );
    }

    s_lotteryState = LotteryState.CALCULATING;

    uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
        i_gasLane, //gasLane
        i_subscriptionId, //Subscription ID that we need for funding requests (here it is to request a random number)
        REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS, //It says how many confirmations the chainlink node should wait before responding
        i_callbackGasLimit, //The limit for how much gas to use for the callback request to our contract's fulfillRandomWords() function.
        NUM_WORDS // number of random words we need
    );
    emit RequestedLotteryWinner(requestId);
}

function fulfillRandomWords(
    uint256 /*requestId*/,
    uint256[] memory randomWords
) internal override {
    uint256 indexOfWinner = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
    address payable recentWinner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
    s_recentWinner = recentWinner;
    s_lotteryState = LotteryState.OPEN;
    s_players = new address payable[](0);
    s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
    (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");

    if (!success) {
        revert Lottery_TransferFailed();
    }
    emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
}

/* view / pure functions*/

function getEnteranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
    return i_enteranceFee;
}

function getPalyers(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
    return s_players[index];
}

function getRecentWinner() public view returns (address) {
    return s_recentWinner;
}

function getLotteryState() public view returns (LotteryState) {
    return s_lotteryState;
}

function getNumWords() public pure returns (uint256) {
    return NUM_WORDS;
}

function getNumberOfPlayers() public view returns (uint256) {
    return s_players.length;
}

function getLatestTimeStamp() public view returns (uint256) {
    return s_lastTimeStamp;
}

function getRequestConfirmations() public pure returns (uint256) {
    return REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS;
}

function getInterval() public view returns (uint256) {
    return i_interval;
}

}
Test Code:
const { network, getNamedAccounts, deployments, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")

!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("Lottery Unit Tests", () => {
          let lottery, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock, lotteryEnteranceFee, deployer, interval
          const chainId = network.config.chainId

          beforeEach(async () => {
              deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
              await deployments.fixture(["all"])
              vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractAt("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", deployer)
              lottery = await ethers.getContractAt("Lottery", deployer)
              lotteryEnteranceFee = await lottery.getEnteranceFee()
              interval = await lottery.getInterval()
          })

          describe("constructor", () => {
              it("initializes the lottery correctly", async () => {
                  //Ideally we make our tests hav just 1 assert per "it"
                  const lotteryState = await lottery.getLotteryState()
                  assert.equal(lotteryState.toString(), "0")
                  assert.equal(interval.toString(), networkConfig[chainId]["interval"])
          })
      })

            describe("Enter lottery", () => {
                it("reverts when you don't pay enough", async () => {
                    await expect(lottery.enterLottery()).to.be.revertedWith(
                        "Lottery__NotEnoughETHEntered",
                    )
                })

                it("records players when they enter", async () => {
                    await lottery.enterLottery({ value: lotteryEnteranceFee })
                    const playerFromContract = await lottery.getPlayer(0)
                    assert.equal(playerFromContract, deployer)
                })

                it("emits event on test", async () => {
                    await expect(lottery.enterLottery({ value: lotteryEnteranceFee })).to.emit(
                        lottery,
                        "LotteryEnter",
                    )
                })

                it("doesn't allow enterance when raffle is calculating", async () => {
                    await lottery.enterLottery({ value: lotteryEnteranceFee })
                    await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [interval.toNumber() + 1])
                    await network.provider.send("evm_mine", [])
                    //We pretend to be a chainlink keeper
                    await lottery.performUpKeep([])
                    await expect(
                        lottery.enterLottery({ value: lotteryEnteranceFee }),
                    ).to.be.revertedWith("Lottery_NotOpen")
                })
            })

            describe("checkUpKeep", () => {
                it("returns false if peoplr haven't sewnt any ETH", async () => {
                    await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [interval.toNumber() + 1])
                    await network.provider.send("evem_mine", [])
                    const { upKeepNeeded } = await lottery.callStatic.checkUpkeep([])
                    assert(![upKeepNeeded])
                })

                it("returns false if lottery isn't open", async function () {
                    await lottery.enterLottery({ value: lotteryEnteranceFee })
                    await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [interval.toNumber() + 1])
                    await network.provider.send("evm_mine", [])
                    await lottery.performUpkeep([])
                    const lotteryState = await lottery.getLotteryState()
                    const { upKeepNeeded } = await lottery.callStatic.checkUpKeep([])
                    assert.equal(lotteryState.toString(), "1")
                    assert.equal(upKeepNeeded, false)
                })

                it("returns false if enough time hasn't passed", async () => {
                    await lottery.enterLottery({ value: lotteryEnteranceFee })
                    await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [interval.toNumber() - 1])
                    await network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine", params: [] })
                    const { upKeepNeeded } = await lottery.callStatic.checkUpKeep("0x")
                    assert(!upKeepNeeded)
                })

                it("returns true if enough time has passed, has players, eth, and is open", async () => {
                    await lottery.enterLottery({ value: lotteryEnteranceFee })
                    await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [interval.toNumber() + 1])
                    await network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine", params: [] })
                    const { upKeepNeeded } = await lottery.callStatic.checkUpKeep("0x")
                    assert(upKeepNeeded)
                })
            })

            describe("performUpKeep", () => {
                it("it can only run if checkUpKeep is true", async () => {
                    await lottery.enterLottery({ vlaue: lotteryEnteranceFee })
                    await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [interval.toNumber() + 1])
                    await network.provider.send("evm_mine", [])
                    const tx = await lottery.performUpKeep([])
                    assert(tx)
                })
            })
  })

Deploy Script:
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

const VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("1")

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId

    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        log("local network detected")
        // const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractAt("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        // log("vrfCoordinatorV2Mock :", vrfCoordinatorV2Mock)
        const deployment = await deployments.get("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractAt(deployment.abi, deployment.address)
        // vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address
        // log("vrfCoordinatorV2Address:", vrfCoordinatorV2Address)
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = deployment.address
        // log('vrfCoordinatorV2Address:', vrfCoordinatorV2Address)
        const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        // log("transactionResponse:" , transactionResponse)
        const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)
        subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId
        //Fund the subscription
        //Usually, you'd need the link token on a real network
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT)
    } else {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }
    

    const enteranceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["enteranceFee"]
    const gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"]
    const callbackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"]
    const interval = networkConfig[chainId]["interval"]

    const args = [
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
        enteranceFee,
        gasLane,
        subscriptionId,
        callbackGasLimit,
        interval,
    ]

    const lottery = await deploy("Lottery", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })

    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("verifying...")
        await verify(lottery.address, args)
    }

    log("-------------------------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "lottery"]

I've ensured that all contracts are deployed and that the vrfCoordinatorV2Mock and lottery contract instances are correctly set. Despite this, the getEnteranceFee call in the beforeEach hook fails with a call revert exception.

You're facing that error because in the second argument to the getContractAt function, you're using deployer. Instead you need to use the address of the contract, which you can fetch using deployments.get (which returns the deployed instance of the particular contract).
So, the revised beforeEach would be:
beforeEach(async () => {
    deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
    await deployments.fixture(["all"])
    const vrfCoordinatorV2MockDeployed = await deployments.get("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
    vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractAt("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", vrfCoordinatorV2MockDeployed.address)
    const lotteryDeployed = await deployments.get("Lottery")
    lottery = await ethers.getContractAt("Lottery", lotteryDeployed.address)
    lotteryEnteranceFee = await lottery.getEnteranceFee()
    interval = await lottery.getInterval()
})

